# how do I nest hidden field values together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, this form submits a `params` hash with a `questions` hash containing all the questions, and a separate answers hash containing all the answers. I'd like to change the form so that the `params` hash submitted will have a `questions` hash containing all the questions, and each of those questions will themselves be a hash containing their own `<%= f.hidden_field "question[#{question_counter}]", value: question.content %>` (4 answers per question). How should I do this?

```
<%= form_for(:quiz_responses, url: quiz_responses_path) do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :name, value: @survey.name %>

<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<ul> 
<%= f.hidden_field "question[#{question_counter}]", value: question.content %>
<%= f.label question.content %>

<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>

<%= f.hidden_field "answer[#{answer_counter}]", value: answer.content %>
<% answer_counter += 1 %>
<%= f.label answer.content %>
<%= f.radio_button("user_answer[#{user_answer_counter}]", answer.content) %>


<% end %>
<% user_answer_counter += 1 %>
</ul>
<% question_counter += 1 %>
<% end #@questions.each do %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end #form_for%>
```

Comment: Have you looked at `fields_for` ? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: yeah I have! but I don't know how to use fields_for if I don't have an associated model to put in it.

Comment: You can do it just using nested associated model (accepts_nested_attributes_for) and fields_for helper for your form

Comment: yeah I know how to use fields_for if I have a model, but this form is submitting to a create action without a model.